# Is memory mapped i/o worthwhile for sequential processing?

Tags: windows, memory-mapped-files

Consider a program that is going to process an entire input file sequentially in one pass.  Is there any advantage to mapping the file into memory versus reading it into a buffer for processing?

- I understand that if you were going to access only portions of the file, then memory mapped i/o can save disk accesses for the portions of the file not needed.  But I'm interested in one sequential pass of the entire file.
- If you were going to read the file (or at least portions of it) multiple times, it might be faster to let the virtual memory system figure out which parts to keep in cache.  But, again, one sequential pass over the entire file won't benefit from this.
- I know that high level i/o (e.g., C++ i/o streams or C functions like fscanf) introduce layers of buffering and abstraction on top of the OS's fundamental read operation.  Let's avoid the language's standard library and focus on the OS call (i.e., `ReadFile` on Windows or `read()` on Linux).

It seems to me the bottleneck (reading the data from the disc) is the same with either approach, yet I hear people claim that memory mapping has less overhead, even in the case of one sequential pass over the entire file.

I'll concede that if two programs are trying to read the same file via memory mapping, then the second can map the same physical pages into its own address space, avoiding the actual disk reads.  Are there any other advantages?

I'm interested primarily in Windows, but bonus points if you can also point out any significant differences with respect to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be. There are probably minor performance gains to be had by not having to issue as many system calls to read the files compared to using MMFs.

From your sequential comment i'm assuming your program is single threaded. If you are performing CPU intensive processing, you can tell the kernel to prefetch the file (with `PrefetchVirtualMemory`) in the background, while you start processing the start of it. Which would be more performant than processing parts of it and calling `ReadFile` in a loop, as you wouldnt have to wait on `ReadFile` to return, or having to wait to read the entire file in to memory yourself before you start processing. Although I suppose you could hack together something similar yourself with async IO, but why reinvent the wheel when the OS can do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I ran an experiment on Windows by modifying a program that reads text files and puts the words into a TRIE.  To focus on the i/o performance, I commented out the actual TRIE operations, so the program just reads the text and breaks it into words.

Results

```
Method
C++ iostreams    228 ms (σ =  6)
Win32 ReadFile   115 ms (σ =  8)
memory mapped    136 ms (σ = 14)
```

Conclusion

The results confirm my suspicion that, for a single sequential pass, there's not a substantial advantage to memory mapping over Win32 ReadFile.  In fact, there may be a small penalty (more system calls?) and more variation.

To be clear, this is just a test on one Windows machine.  I've heard plausible explanations why mmap on Linux may be faster.

Unsurprisingly, the extra layer of buffering in the C++ iostreams library made it the slowest method.

Methods

For input, I used 18 books from Project Guttenberg, totaling 10,558,803 bytes.  The books are primarily ASCII but some include a few non-ASCII characters encoded as UTF-8.

The main program loop opens a file, reads (or maps) the entire file into memory in one pass, tokenizes it, and then closes (or unmaps) the file.

The tokenization is a hand-written state machine that builds a `std::string_view` for each word.  It operates sequentially reading each byte exactly once.  I kept the tokenization to ensure an apples-to-apples comparison between the file reading solutions versus the memory mapped solution, which might not otherwise have brought the data into memory.

Coded in C++, compiled into a 64-bit executable with MSVC 2019 with `/EHsc /O2 /std:c++latest`.  Executed on an Intel-based desktop with SSD.

Each experiment was run seven times with a hot cache.  Times were recorded with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` and reported in milliseconds.  The tokenizer reported identical bytes read and words found on each run regardless of method.

C++ iostreams method:

The files are opened in binary mode, so that there's no effort wasted translating CR+LF to `'\n'`.  We read each file into a `std::string` in one go.

```
auto file = std::ifstream(file_name, std::ios::binary);
std::string text{std::istreambuf_iterator(file), {}};
file.close();
Tokenize(text);
```

Win32 ReadFile method:

Note that we hinted with `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` and that there's no error checking.  We used a single ReadFile call for each file, bringing the data into a `std::string` which is pre-allocated and zero-initialized using the file size.

Memory mapped method

We open the file with the identical options (notably `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN`.  There are additional system calls (CreateFileMapping, MapViewOfFiew, UnMapViewOfFile, and an additional CloseHandle) compared to the ReadFile method.